# Calling Google Earth Engine scripts using Python?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I have some scripts in the Earth Engine Code Editor.

Is it possible to call these scripts remotely using Python API?

Comment: In theory yes, possibly with very roundabout ways and browser emulation. What exactly is your use case? Earth Engine provides a set of tools that allow for automated execution, from server side apps to a dedicated Python API.

Comment: @Kersten I would like to avoid browser emulation. We have scientists working on the scripts in the Code Editor. The idea is plug in these scripts into a larger project. Seems that server side apps is the only realistic option to do a remote calls

Comment: Well, you could adapt the scripts to use the [Python API](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install). That might be easiest way to have control over over the execution time with cron or other triggers.

Comment: Dear all, did you find a solution for requering custom scripts developed in JS code editor directly in Python? (e.g. script = ee.require('users/user/repository:custom_functions')

Answer (score 1):

For easy interactive use of the Python API, there is `geemap`. It also has a module to convert Javascript scripts and snippets [to Python](https://geemap.org/conversion/#geemap.conversion.js_to_python)

Given a Javascript script `some_script` in the working directory, you can call it like so (untested):

```py
from geemap import js_to_python
js_to_python(in_file="some_script.js",out_file="some_script.py",use_qgis=False)
```

and your function is in `some_script.py`.